# How to calculate average using case when and distinct count?

Tags: sql, hive

My source table contains sales information. Each row is a person and records every time they've shopped/where. I can therefore calculate the average transaction value per industry by the following:

```
select 
    industry,
    COALESCE(AVG(CASE WHEN shopcode  in (1,2,4) THEN dollar END), 0) AS avt
from sales 
group by industry
```

But how can I adapt this to calculate the spend per distinct count of user i.e.: `sum(dollar)/count(distinct person)` so similar to above but instead of `sum/count(*) sum/count(distinct person)`... I need to use coalesce with this as well.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  What is the filtering on `shop_code`.  It is in the query but not at all explained in the question.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i adapt this to calculate the spend per distinct count of user i.e.: sum(dollar)/count(distinct person)

You can use:

```
select industry,
       sum(dollar) / count(distinct person)
from sales 
group by industry;
```

I'm not sure what the filtering on `shop_code` is for.  It is in your query but not part of the question.  If you want this for particular shops, I would suggest moving this to a `where` clause:

```
select industry,
       sum(dollar) / count(distinct person)
from sales 
where shop_code in (1, 2, 4)
group by industry;
```